# O que $@ quer dizer em shell script?

Tags: shell-script

Estou analisando algumas funções em Shell Script e me deparei com esse código:

```
adicionar_usuario()
{
  USUARIO=$1
  SENHA=$2

  shift; shift;

  COMENTARIO=$@
  echo useradd -c "$COMENTARIO" $USUARIO
  echo passwd $USUARIO $SENHA
  echo "$USUARIO ($COMENTARIO) com a senha $SENHA adicionado."
}
```

Minha dúvida é o que p `$@` significa e o que `shift` está fazendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine que o comando a ser executado será:

```
$ adiciona_usuario anderson m1nh4_s3nh4 "Anderson Carlos Woss"
```

Serão 3 parâmetros. O primeiro será utilizado para o usuário e o segundo para a senha:

```
USUARIO=$1
SENHA=$2
```

Já o comando `$@` retorna **todos** os parâmetros passados para o *script*. Neste caso, seria:

```
COMENTARIO="anderson m1nh4_s3nh4 \"Anderson Carlos Woss\""
```

Como já foram utilizados os dados de usuário e senha, é utilizado o comando `shift`, que remove do início da lista de parâmetros o primeiro. Assim, executando o comando duas vezes será removido tanto o usuário quanto a senha.

A saída do programa seria algo parecido com:

```
anderson (Anderson Carlos Woss) com a senha m1nh4_s3nh4 adicionado.
```